# How to avoid sudden spikes in batch size in Spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am streaming data from kafka and trying to limit the number of events per batch to 10 events. After processing for 10-15 batches, there is a sudden spike in the batch size. Below are my settings:

```
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=1

spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true

spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate=1

spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate=2
```

[Please check this image for the streaming behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOxoT.png)

Comment: How are you setting these configurations in your spark context/ spark-submit? Can we get  a code example please?
I find it somewhat strange that you are receiving 9 events per batch, since according to documentation you should be getting 2*3=6 (max_rate * batch_duration)

Comment: I am adding these configuration using spark-submit.Using --conf spark_streaming_config.conf. The .conf file has all my configs

Comment: Check environment tab on sparUI to confirm if your settings passed correctly

Comment: I would confirm that the above-mentioned parameters are being set when the job is run by looking at the Environment tab first.Are you using direct API for Kafka and Spark streaming integration or receiver-based Kafka-Spark integration?

Answer (score 1):

This is the bug in spark, please reffer to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18371

The pull request isn't merged yet, but you may pick it up and build spark on your own.

To summarize the issue:

If you have the `spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate` set to a number <= partition count, then an effective rate of 0 is calculated:

```
val totalLag = lagPerPartition.values.sum
...
    val backpressureRate = Math.round(lag / totalLag.toFloat * rate)
...
```

(the second line calculates rate per partition where `rate` is rate comming from PID and defaults to minRate, when PID calculates it shall be smaller)
As here: [DirectKafkaInputDStream code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8532e26f335b67b74c976712ad82c20ea6dbbf80/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala#L107)

This resulting to 0 causes the fallback to (unreasonable) head of partitions:

```
    ...
    if (effectiveRateLimitPerPartition.values.sum > 0) {
      val secsPerBatch = context.graph.batchDuration.milliseconds.toDouble / 1000
      Some(effectiveRateLimitPerPartition.map {
        case (tp, limit) => tp -> (secsPerBatch * limit).toLong
      })
    } else {
      None
    }

    ...

maxMessagesPerPartition(offsets).map { mmp =>
  mmp.map { case (tp, messages) =>
    val lo = leaderOffsets(tp)
    tp -> lo.copy(offset = Math.min(currentOffsets(tp) + messages, lo.offset))
  }
}.getOrElse(leaderOffsets)
```

As in [DirectKafkaInputDStream#clamp](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8532e26f335b67b74c976712ad82c20ea6dbbf80/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala#L149)

This makes the backpressure basically not working when your actual and minimal receive rate/msg/ partitions is smaller ~ equal to partitions count and you experience significant lag (e.g. messages come in spikes and you have constant processing powers).